# Is there a solution to running out of undos in Corel X6?

Tags: workflow, corel-draw

I have created a bitmap from a vector image. After editing a while, I wanted to scrap the idea and return to the vector image, but my undos have run out.

Is there any way to get the vector back?

Comment: Always work with duplicates. It is handy to keep a hidden layer with 'spare parts' you may need later, especially when you are making an irreversible change like rasterizing. Also saving file versions helps too.

Answer (score 4):

You can manually increase the Undo steps in `Tools > Options > Workspace > General` (i think the default number is 20). I've seen people work with 100-200 Undos without having performace issues, but keep in mind that these steps are saved as temporary files and do use some computer resources.

Unfortunately, if you are trying to recover a step that was beyong your default number of Undos, there isn't much you can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to make a big change like that, you would be better off saving your vector file and then making a copy to change to bitmap. That way, if you don't like your changes the old version is available.

Working with undos is easier, until you run out of them or the program crashes. Then you're in trouble!